# Html5 multiple point locations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I am building a web app and would like to place multiple points on a map. Before posting, I read previous threads and find some components as Gmap or batchgeo. Which apis are currently more suitable? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
      type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 750px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 11,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps API v3 is certainly very suitable for placing points on maps, as Ankur's answer illustrates.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/